# Unable to setup json-smart with gradle

Tags: java, json, gradle, spring-boot

I have spring boot project with gradle. I would like to use [json-smart](https://code.google.com/p/json-smart/)  library to process small json data stored in MySQL String records.

Here is my dependencies in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.10.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    compile("net.minidev:json-smart:2.2")
    runtime("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

I can successfully run command:

```
gradlew clean build
```

But I can not import JSONValue object. Seems that gradle didn't download all dependencies. Here are my dependencies: [dependencies screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg7Wk.png)
and here is [output from  gradlew clean build command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl84U.png)

How I can manage to import and use json-smart JSONValue object?

Comment: Try: `gradle clean --refresh-dependencies build`

Comment: Not works. I have lost hard disk and after reinstall OS this is solved. But the very same problem I have with another library: compile("com.mandrillapp.wrapper.lutung:lutung:0.0.5") ... It compiles but in the external libraries I can not see MandrillApi and can not use it inside project as well .. can not compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what helps me.

To refresh dependencies after changes made in a Gradle script, in the Gradle tool window, click refresh button.
On pressing this button, IntelliJ IDEA parses the project structure, and displays detected differences (if any) in the Gradle tool window.

I have found solution on the jetbrains site: [Synchronizing Changes in Gradle Project and IntelliJ IDEA Project](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html)